# How to convert local time to UTC?

Tags: postgresql

I need to convert local time to UTC using a function. The inputs I have is the local time, timezone of the local time (e.g. 'Pacific/Auckland'). What I need to get from the procedure is the UTC time for the local time based on given timezone.

Can someone please help?

I am using version 8.3

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is covered in the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT), but it's not always obvious how to actually work with dates/times. The SQL spec is a bit bizarre.

In the case of your question it isn't clear whether you want to store the time in UTC but display it in the server's local time (`TimeZone`), or whether you wan to ignore `TimeZone` and always display it as UTC. I'll assume the latter.

For timestamps you'd just use `AT TIME ZONE` twice, like:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-08-13 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Sydney' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

You need to use `AT TIME ZONE` twice. Once to convert the input `timestamp` to `timestamptz` according to the argument timezone, then another to convert that to a `timestamp` at UTC.

Unfortunately because of the (IMO insane) way the SQL spec defines `AT TIME ZONE` for `TIME`, you can't do the same thing for `TIME`. You'll have to manipulate the `TimeZone` variable instead:

```
SET TimeZone = 'UTC';
SELECT TIME '07:00' AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Sydney';
```

This still leaves you with a `timetz` not a `time`. So its display value changes with the `timezone` setting.

Comment: +1 for the set TimeZone, this was the piece I was missing for trying to convert my timestamp without timezones to utc timestampstz's. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `select now() at time zone 'UTC'` for postgresql.