# Data displayed with a time-shift, not the original time

Tags: sql, grafana, timescaledb

I just started using Grafana and I am new to SQL as well. I posted this on Grafana community as well, but got no response yet. I set up a simple dashboard with timescaleDB for grafana and the time data was added in the Postgres database as "timestamp without timezone" (e.g:- in the format of '2020-04-27 22:38:36' etc.) In the dashboard, data does not get displayed for the current time while the DB being updated/data does not get displayed for the actual time data was written to the database but displayed with a time shift, when actual data was written at 11.mm.ss they are displayed for 17.mm.ss on the graph. (as here - [dashboard picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5my7.png)) (below is the query I make to get the output result shown in the image (I have only written data to the database for an interval of time))

```
SELECT
 "time" AS "time",
  score
FROM scoredata
WHERE
"time" BETWEEN '2020-04-27T11:20:35.925Z' AND '2020-04-27T12:20:35.925Z'
ORDER BY 1
```

I have tried changing the timezone from the dashboard setting as well. But gave no change to the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the Grafana community page. The data needed to be stored in UTC in the database. Grafana will convert them to the local time.

Answer (score 3):

Officially the time column must be in UTC time to be diplayed correct. If this is not the case, you can convert it. I have a PostgreSQL database with local time. To use it correctly in Grafana, I use

```
   $__timeGroupAlias(time at TIME zone 'Europe/Berlin' at TIME zone 'UTC',$__interval,0),
```

with `time` as the name of the time column. In the time filter the same has to be done

```
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(time at TIME zone 'Europe/Berlin' at TIME zone 'UTC')
```

Credits to [How to convert local time to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188151/how-to-convert-local-time-to-utc)