# Is there a SQL function to convert to PST or PDT depending on the date?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone, dst

I would like to convert times from pacific to UTC. However, I must first convert the times to either PST or PDT depending on the date. Is there a SQL function that can do this, or does anyone have any advice for creating this function?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: I am not sure what dbms I am using. How can I find this info? Are you suggesting that I create my own function?

Comment: Most databases have their own functions, unfortunately different ones.

Comment: Try `select version();`, `select service_level from sysibmadm.env_inst_info;`, `select * from V$VERSION;`, `select @@version;` - anyone working?

Comment: Thanks! I have PostgreSQL 10.16 (Ubuntu 10.16-1.pgdg16.04+1)

Comment: I am looking here: https://popsql.com/learn-sql/postgresql/how-to-convert-utc-to-local-time-zone-in-postgresql

I am trying to convert from 'america/los_angeles' to 'utc' (just the reverse of the first example). Just wondering if daylight savings time is taken into account in that conversion. I assume daylight savings time is not taken into account in the second example because utc is being converted to pst (would want to convert to pdt depending on the date).

Comment: `at time zone 'pst' at time zone 'utc'` and `at time zone 'pdt' at time zone 'utc'` will give you different results, 1 hour difference. And `select timestamp'2021-06-01 11:23:39' at time zone 'america/los_angeles' at time zone 'utc'` returns the same as 'pdt', just as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert local time to UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188151/how-to-convert-local-time-to-utc)

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is pretty much useless as a guide to timestamps. If you are going to work with timezones then store your timestamps in a `timestamp with time zone` field. The `timezone` will not actually be stored but the timestamp will be stored as a `UTC`. Whenever a `timestamp` is entered it is rotated to a `UTC` value. This makes working with value easier down the road. If you want to take into account `DST` transitions you will need to use full timezone names e.g. `US/Pacific`, as they cover the two offsets(`PST/PDT`) that constitute the standard/daylight savings timezones. As you found using the offset `PST(-08)` or `PDT(-07)` gets you a fixed offset regardless of date.